# How to show windows form in the center of Excel window in VSTO AddIn

Tags: excel, vb.net, winforms, vsto

I need to show a customer form in the center of the active Excel window. FormStartPosition.CenterParent doesn't work.
I tried the following code

```
Private Sub myForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application

    Me.Left = app.Left + app.Width / 2 - Me.Width / 2
    Me.Top = app.Top + app.Height / 2 - Me.Height / 2

End Sub
```

Sadly, the above code doesn't work as I expected. The form is not positioned in the center of the Excel application. I suspect that app.Width and Me.Width use different units. Please, help me, if you know how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Winform Size is in **pixel** and ExcelApp in **points** so you need `app.ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsX`

```
Private Sub myForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application

    Me.Left = app.ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsX(app.Left) + _
        app.ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsX(app.Width) / 2 - _
        Me.Width / 2
    Me.Top = app.ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsX(app.Top) + _
        app.ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsX(app.Height) / 2 - _
        Me.Height / 2

End Sub
```

I didn't test but it should work for you.

Another approach is to use `ShowDialog` to display your form and set `StartPosition` property to `CenterParent`